# Run sql query from If else block in shell script

Tags: sql, shell, if-statement

I want to connect sql db and execute sql query from shell script. I tried using this

```
if float_cmp "$size1 > 7.50"; then
    echo "### THE DATA SIZE IS GREATER THAN 7.5 GB ###"
    echo "############### DROPPING CREATED $IMPUSER USER ###########################"
    ${PATH_TO_CLIENT}sqlplus $EXPUSER/$EXPPWD@$ENDPOINT<< EOF
    drop user $IMPUSER cascade;
    exit;
    EOF
    exit 1
else
    echo "### THE DATA SIZE IS OKAY ###"
fi
```

The statement is working outside if block but throwing error when executing in IF block

```
line 80: warning: here-document at line 72 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
line 81: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: No trailing blanks are allowed around `EOF`. You should not indent the lines inside of the here-document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the indentation inside of the here-document:

```
if float_cmp "$size1 > 7.50"; then
    echo "### THE DATA SIZE IS GREATER THAN 7.5 GB ###"
    echo "############### DROPPING CREATED $IMPUSER USER ###########################"
    "${PATH_TO_CLIENT}"sqlplus $EXPUSER/$EXPPWD@$ENDPOINT<< EOF
drop user $IMPUSER cascade;
exit;
EOF
    exit 1
else
    echo "### THE DATA SIZE IS OKAY ###"
fi
```